# Find a substring in cells across multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with 50+ columns which I'm simplifying here below:

```
students = [('Samurai', 34, '777.0', 'usa--->jp', 'usd--->yen') ,
            ('Jack', 31, '555.5','usa','usd') ,
            ('Mojo', 16,'488.1','n/a','n/a') ,
            ('Jojo', 32,'119.11','uk--->usa','pound--->usd')]

# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Balance', 'Country','Currency'])
```

[image]

I'm trying to find

a) whether there are any instances of '--->' in any of the cells across the DataFrame?

b) if so where? (optional)

So far I've tried 2 approaches

```
boolDf = df.isin(['--->']).any().any()
```

this only works for strings not substrings

```
columns = list(df)
for col in columns:    
    df[col].str.find('--->', 0).any()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

(I believe this may only work for columns with string types)

Would appreciate any help. Open to other approaches as well.

Comment: Have you tried googling to see if this question has already been asked? If not, try [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Yes, I only found solutions that work for a specified individual column, not the entire data frame. Would appreciate any links if there is a similar question out there. Going to try your suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap) to test each individual value in a dataframe.

```
>>> df
      Name  Age Balance    Country      Currency
0  Samurai   34   777.0  usa--->jp    usd--->yen
1     Jack   31   555.5        usa           usd
2     Mojo   16   488.1        n/a           n/a
3     Jojo   32  119.11  uk--->usa  pound--->usd

>>> df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and '--->' in x)
    Name    Age  Balance  Country  Currency
0  False  False    False     True      True
1  False  False    False    False     False
2  False  False    False    False     False
3  False  False    False     True      True
```

To use the `.str` accessor you can:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('--->'))
    Name  Balance  Country  Currency
0  False    False     True      True
1  False    False    False     False
2  False    False    False     False
3  False    False     True      True
```

The output differs a little - note the `Age` column is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Get a boolean map of the rows that contain the substring:

```
substr_rows = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('--->').any(), axis=1)
```

Do any of the rows contain the substring?

```
substr_rows.any()

True
```

which ones?

```
substr_rows

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

students = [('Samurai', 34, '777.0', 'usa--->jp', 'usd--->yen') ,
            ('Jack', 31, '555.5','usa','usd') ,
            ('Mojo', 16,'488.1','n/a','n/a') ,
            ('Jojo', 32,'119.11','uk--->usa','pound--->usd')]

# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Balance', 'Country','Currency'])

def find_substr(df:pd.DataFrame,substr:str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    df: pd.DataFrame we want to search
    substr: the string that we are looking for in all string columns
    returns df of boolean values
    """
    # create new df to house bool values (if substring is found)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # loop through the columns
    for col in df.columns:
        # if the series is a string we will search for it
        if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df[col]):
            # the series of our new df represent if we found the substring
            new_df[col] = df[col].str.contains(substr)

    return new_df

found_str = find_substr(df,'--->')

found_str
# -- OUTPUT -- 
    Name  Balance  Country  Currency
0  False    False     True      True
1  False    False    False     False
2  False    False    False     False
3  False    False     True      True
```

This function should work it gives you a new df of boolean values for each cell where you found the substring.

edit:
This uses `pd.Series.str.contains()` to find each string that contains your substring. Read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `str.contains` for each column to identify which cell contains a particular string:

```
out = df.astype(str).apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('--->'))
```

Output:

```
    Name    Age  Balance  Country  Currency
0  False  False    False     True      True
1  False  False    False    False     False
2  False  False    False    False     False
3  False  False    False     True      True
```

Then `out.any().any()` will produce True.

As a one-liner:

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('--->')).any().any()
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions, here's another.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    col: df[col].str.contains('--->') for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
})

    Name  Balance  Country  Currency
0  False    False     True      True
1  False    False    False     False
2  False    False    False     False
3  False    False     True      True
```

And another

```
pd.concat([s.str.contains('--->') for col, s in df.iteritems()
    if hasattr(s, 'str')], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolDf = df['Country'].where(df['Country'].str.contains('--->'))
df_filter=boolDf.isnull()
df[~df_filter]
```